# Dragon NaturallySpeaking software not calling onAfterChange event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, speech-recognition, naturallyspeaking

I am unable to get Dragon NaturallySpeaking 11 to fire an onkeyup event in JavaScript that works fine when a user types into the textbox. Does this software act differently than a keyboard copying and pasting text into a focused textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dragon dictation changes the text by sending messages (i.e., EM_REPLACESEL or WM_SETTEXT) instead of triggering keyboard events (i.e., onkeydown, onkeyup, or onkeypress).